# Замена строк в мемо

Tags: delphi

Работаю с мемо.

Идут пошагово три задачи: сначала в `memo1` загружается файл, потом строки из `memo1` перемешиваются, далее надо их вывести в тоже самое `memo`, заменив тот текст, который был. Была рассмотрена также замена строк такого вида:

```
 Text : string;
 begin
    Memo.Lines.Text := 'Замена текста в Memo';
    Text := StringReplace(Memo.Lines.Text, 'Memo', 'компоненте Memo', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    Memo.Lines.Text := Text;
```

Но у меня динамический массив строк в мемо. Использую три мемо все работает, но это довольно некомпактно, хотелось бы сделать все в одном мемо.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

**вот часть кода, идет загрузка текстового файла до определенной строки,номер этйо строки  задавается пользователем в эдит.
с мемо было так**

```
var
   i,k:integer;
   sl: tstringlist;
begin
          k:= StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
          sl:=tstringlist.create;
          sl.loadfromfile('Text.txt'); 
          for i := 0 to k - 1 do    Memo1.Lines.Add(sl[i]);
          sl.Free;
```

Пробую с  tstringlist .. 
    var 
    sl: tstringlist;//массив для дальнейшей работы с ним
    sl1: tstringlist;//массив для загрузки файла 
     i,k:integer;
    begin
       kurs:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text) ;

```
   if  ((kurs=1)  and (ComboBox1.ItemIndex=0))
     then
          k:= StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
          sl1:=tstringlist.create;
          sl1.loadfromfile('MyFile.txt');
           for i := 0 to k - 1 do
            sl.Add(sl1[i]);//так же sl.Add(sl1.Strings[used[i]]); тоже возникает ошибка(
          sl.Free;
```

Comment: вы вызываете sl.Free;, а потом вызываете sl.Add, вот у вас и ошибка, обращение к уничтоженному объекту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое для вас - использовать одно мемо и два экземпляра `TStringList`. Тогда, грубо говоря, `Memo2.Lines` достаточно будет заменить на `StringList1`, а `Memo3.Lines` на `StringList2`. Мемо, которое используется для отображения, трогать не будем.

Comment: то есть stringlist отображаться не будет и будет использоваться только для работы с его элементами?
и сложно ли заменить вывод массивов из мемо в стринглист? просто работа уже почти готовая

Comment: Да, дело в том, что в Delphi есть визуальный класс TMemo, который отображается, внутри него есть поле Lines, в котором хранятся данные. Этот класс абсолютно совместим с TStringList, поэтому переделывать практически ничего не придётся, если остались сложности - пришлите фрагмент кода с тремя Memo, поправлю на вариант с StringList. Просто на словах сложнее всё объяснить пытаться.

Comment: в своем сообщение добавила код..что пробовала